# Error: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, reactjs, graphql, gatsby

When I run gatsby build/develop I get multiple identical errors

```
    (node:22611) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added to [PassThrough]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
    (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

I ran "node --trace warnings ..." and here is the output:

```
    node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:936
      throw err;
      ^

    Error: Cannot find module '/Users/soroush/gatsby-test/gatsby-wordpress-starter-files-main'
        at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
        at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
        at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
        at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
      code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
      requireStack: []
    }

    Node.js v17.3.1
```

Looking through similar posts, I have gone though a couple of suggested solutions but nothing has worked yet.

Anybody run into the same issue with Gatsby?

**EDIT 1:** Here is the package.json and gatsby-config.js

package.json :

```
{
    "name": "removed",
    "private": true,
    "description": "removed",
    "version": "1.0",
    "author": "removed",
    "dependencies": {
        "@apollo/client": "^3.5.7",
        "@emotion/react": "^11.7.1",
        "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
        "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
        "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^2.0.2",
        "dotenv": "^14.0.0",
        "gatsby": "^4.5.3",
        "gatsby-cli": "^4.5.2",
        "gatsby-image": "^3.11.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-google-fonts": "^1.0.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-google-gtag": "^4.5.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-image": "^2.5.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^4.5.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "^4.1.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^5.5.1",
        "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^5.5.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-remote-images": "^3.2.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^4.4.0",
        "gatsby-plugin-styled-components": "^5.5.0",
        "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^4.5.2",
        "gatsby-source-google-spreadsheet": "^2.0.0",
        "gatsby-source-wordpress": "^6.5.1",
        "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^4.4.0",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
        "react": "^17.0.1",
        "react-calendly": "^2.2.2",
        "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "styled-components": "^5.3.3",
        "underscore": "^1.13.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "prettier": "2.5.1"
    },
    "keywords": [
        "gatsby"
    ],
    "license": "0BSD",
    "scripts": {
        "build": "gatsby build",
        "develop": "gatsby develop",
        "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
        "start": "npm run develop",
        "serve": "gatsby serve",
        "clean": "gatsby clean",
        "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
    },
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "graphql": "15.7.2"
    }
}
```

gatsby-config.js :

```
require("dotenv").config({
  path: `.env.${process.env.NODE_ENV}`,
}),

module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    title: `removed`,
    description: `removed`,
    author: `removed`,
  },
  plugins: [
    `gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
    `gatsby-plugin-material-ui`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `images`,
        path: `${__dirname}/src/images`,
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-gtag`,
      options: {
        // You can add multiple tracking ids and a pageview event will be fired for all of them.
        trackingIds: [
         process.env.GA_TRACKING_ID, // Google Analytics / GA
          // "AW-CONVERSION_ID", // Google Ads / Adwords / AW
          // "DC-FLOODIGHT_ID", // Marketing Platform advertising products (Display & Video 360, Search Ads 360, and Campaign Manager)
        ],
        // // This object gets passed directly to the gtag config command
        // // This config will be shared across all trackingIds
        // gtagConfig: {
        //   optimize_id: "OPT_CONTAINER_ID",
        //   anonymize_ip: true,
        //   cookie_expires: 0,
        // },
        // This object is used for configuration specific to this plugin
        pluginConfig: {
          // Puts tracking script in the head instead of the body
          head: true,
          // Setting this parameter is also optional

        },
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: 'gatsby-source-google-spreadsheet',
      options: {
        spreadsheetId: process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_SPREADSHEET_ID,
        spreadsheetName: 'Courses',
        credentials: {
          "type": "service_account",
          "project_id": "project1-293323",
          "private_key_id": process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
          "private_key": process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_PRIVATE_KEY,
          "client_email": process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_CLIENT_EMAIL,
          "client_id": process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_CLIENT_ID,
          "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
          "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
          "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
          "client_x509_cert_url": process.env.GATSBY_GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS_CLIENT_CERT
          },
        filterNode: () => true,
        mapNode: node => node
      }
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-image`,
    `gatsby-transformer-sharp`,
    `gatsby-plugin-sharp`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-manifest`,
      options: {
        name: `gatsby-starter-default`,
        short_name: `starter`,
        start_url: `/`,
        background_color: `#663399`,
        theme_color: `#663399`,
        display: `minimal-ui`,
        icon: `src/images/gatsby-icon.png`, // This path is relative to the root of the site.
      },
    },
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-wordpress`,
      options: {
        // you need to update this path to make the website
        url: `http://erndgatsbycourse.local/graphql`,
      },
    },
  
    {
      resolve: "gatsby-plugin-remote-images",
      options: {
        nodeType: `GoogleSpreadsheetCoursesMain`,
        imagePath: `image`,
        name: `optimized_course_image`,
      },
    },
    `gatsby-plugin-styled-components`,
    {
      resolve: `gatsby-plugin-google-fonts`,
      options: {
        fonts: [`Teko\:200, 400, 500, 600, 700`],
        display: `swap`,
      },
    },
```

**Edit 2:**

npm audit report is showing multiple vulnerabilities. `npm audit fix --force` doesn't work and somehow downgrades many of the dependencies in package.json and breaks the code completely.

```
# npm audit report

ansi-html  *
Severity: high
Uncontrolled Resource Consumption in ansi-html - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-whgm-jr23-g3j9
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gatsby@2.19.38, which is a breaking change
node_modules/ansi-html
  @gatsbyjs/webpack-hot-middleware  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
  node_modules/@gatsbyjs/webpack-hot-middleware
    gatsby  2.3.24-ink.60 - 2.3.24-ink.61 || 2.4.0-0 - 2.4.0-alpha.3 || >=2.6.0-alpha.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @gatsbyjs/webpack-hot-middleware
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-cli
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    node_modules/gatsby
      babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries  >=2.17.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries
      gatsby-plugin-catch-links  >=2.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-catch-links
        gatsby-source-wordpress  2.0.57-0 - 2.0.57-17 || 2.1.0-alpha.03b9df85 - 3.0.0-rc.9 || 3.11.0-alpha-wordpress.44 - 3.11.0-next.0 || >=3.12.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @rematch/immer
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-catch-links
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-image
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
        node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress
      gatsby-plugin-google-gtag  >=2.9.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag
      gatsby-plugin-image  >=0.8.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image
      gatsby-plugin-manifest  >=2.4.36
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest
      gatsby-plugin-material-ui  >=3.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui
      gatsby-plugin-offline  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-offline
      gatsby-plugin-page-creator  >=2.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-page-creator
      gatsby-plugin-react-helmet  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet
      gatsby-plugin-sharp  >=2.0.31
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp
        gatsby-transformer-sharp  >=2.13.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp
      gatsby-plugin-styled-components  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-styled-components
      gatsby-plugin-typescript  >=2.13.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-typescript
      gatsby-plugin-utils  0.2.27-qod.19 - 0.2.27-qod.21 || 0.2.31-query-modules-debug-missing-sq.23 || >=0.2.35
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-utils
      gatsby-source-filesystem  >=2.12.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-remote-images/node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem
      node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem
        gatsby-plugin-remote-images  >=3.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
        node_modules/gatsby-plugin-remote-images
  @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin  <=0.5.0-rc.6
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-html
  node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin

ansi-regex  >2.1.1 <5.0.1
Severity: moderate
 Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in chalk/ansi-regex - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-93q8-gq69-wqmw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gatsby@2.19.38, which is a breaking change
node_modules/ansi-regex
  strip-ansi  4.0.0 - 5.2.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ansi-regex
  node_modules/strip-ansi
    gatsby  2.3.24-ink.60 - 2.3.24-ink.61 || 2.4.0-0 - 2.4.0-alpha.3 || >=2.6.0-alpha.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @gatsbyjs/webpack-hot-middleware
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-cli
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    node_modules/gatsby
      babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries  >=2.17.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries
      gatsby-plugin-catch-links  >=2.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-catch-links
        gatsby-source-wordpress  2.0.57-0 - 2.0.57-17 || 2.1.0-alpha.03b9df85 - 3.0.0-rc.9 || 3.11.0-alpha-wordpress.44 - 3.11.0-next.0 || >=3.12.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @rematch/immer
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-catch-links
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-image
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
        node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress
      gatsby-plugin-google-gtag  >=2.9.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag
      gatsby-plugin-image  >=0.8.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image
      gatsby-plugin-manifest  >=2.4.36
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest
      gatsby-plugin-material-ui  >=3.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui
      gatsby-plugin-offline  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-offline
      gatsby-plugin-page-creator  >=2.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-page-creator
      gatsby-plugin-react-helmet  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet
      gatsby-plugin-sharp  >=2.0.31
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp
        gatsby-transformer-sharp  >=2.13.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp
      gatsby-plugin-styled-components  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-styled-components
      gatsby-plugin-typescript  >=2.13.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-typescript
      gatsby-plugin-utils  0.2.27-qod.19 - 0.2.27-qod.21 || 0.2.31-query-modules-debug-missing-sq.23 || >=0.2.35
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-utils
      gatsby-source-filesystem  >=2.12.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-remote-images/node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem
      node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem
        gatsby-plugin-remote-images  >=3.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
        node_modules/gatsby-plugin-remote-images
    gatsby-cli  2.5.9-ink.60 - 2.5.9-ink.61 || >=2.6.0-0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    Depends on vulnerable versions of yurnalist
    node_modules/gatsby-cli
    yurnalist  >=1.0.5
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    node_modules/yurnalist

browserslist  4.0.0 - 4.16.4
Severity: moderate
Regular Expression Denial of Service in browserslist - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-w8qv-6jwh-64r5
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gatsby@2.19.38, which is a breaking change
node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/browserslist
  react-dev-utils  6.0.0-next.03604a46 - 12.0.0-next.60
  Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
  Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    gatsby  2.3.24-ink.60 - 2.3.24-ink.61 || 2.4.0-0 - 2.4.0-alpha.3 || >=2.6.0-alpha.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @gatsbyjs/webpack-hot-middleware
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-cli
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    node_modules/gatsby
      babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries  >=2.17.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries
      gatsby-plugin-catch-links  >=2.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-catch-links
        gatsby-source-wordpress  2.0.57-0 - 2.0.57-17 || 2.1.0-alpha.03b9df85 - 3.0.0-rc.9 || 3.11.0-alpha-wordpress.44 - 3.11.0-next.0 || >=3.12.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of @rematch/immer
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-catch-links
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-image
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
        node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress
      gatsby-plugin-google-gtag  >=2.9.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag
      gatsby-plugin-image  >=0.8.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image
      gatsby-plugin-manifest  >=2.4.36
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest
      gatsby-plugin-material-ui  >=3.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui
      gatsby-plugin-offline  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-offline
      gatsby-plugin-page-creator  >=2.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-page-creator
      gatsby-plugin-react-helmet  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet
      gatsby-plugin-sharp  >=2.0.31
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp
        gatsby-transformer-sharp  >=2.13.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp
      gatsby-plugin-styled-components  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-styled-components
      gatsby-plugin-typescript  >=2.13.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-typescript
      gatsby-plugin-utils  0.2.27-qod.19 - 0.2.27-qod.21 || 0.2.31-query-modules-debug-missing-sq.23 || >=0.2.35
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-utils
      gatsby-source-filesystem  >=2.12.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-remote-images/node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem
      node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem
        gatsby-plugin-remote-images  >=3.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
        node_modules/gatsby-plugin-remote-images

immer  <=9.0.5
Severity: critical
Prototype Pollution in immer - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-33f9-j839-rf8h
Prototype Pollution in immer - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-9qmh-276g-x5pj
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gatsby@2.19.38, which is a breaking change
node_modules/immer
node_modules/react-dev-utils/node_modules/immer
  @rematch/immer  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
  node_modules/@rematch/immer
    gatsby-source-wordpress  2.0.57-0 - 2.0.57-17 || 2.1.0-alpha.03b9df85 - 3.0.0-rc.9 || 3.11.0-alpha-wordpress.44 - 3.11.0-next.0 || >=3.12.0-next.0
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @rematch/immer
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-catch-links
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-image
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
    node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress
  react-dev-utils  6.0.0-next.03604a46 - 12.0.0-next.60
  Depends on vulnerable versions of browserslist
  Depends on vulnerable versions of immer
  node_modules/react-dev-utils
    gatsby  2.3.24-ink.60 - 2.3.24-ink.61 || 2.4.0-0 - 2.4.0-alpha.3 || >=2.6.0-alpha.1
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @gatsbyjs/webpack-hot-middleware
    Depends on vulnerable versions of @pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-cli
    Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of react-dev-utils
    Depends on vulnerable versions of strip-ansi
    node_modules/gatsby
      babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries  >=2.17.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/babel-plugin-remove-graphql-queries
      gatsby-plugin-catch-links  >=2.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-catch-links
      gatsby-plugin-google-gtag  >=2.9.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-google-gtag
      gatsby-plugin-image  >=0.8.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image
      gatsby-plugin-manifest  >=2.4.36
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-manifest
      gatsby-plugin-material-ui  >=3.0.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-material-ui
      gatsby-plugin-offline  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-offline
      gatsby-plugin-page-creator  >=2.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-page-creator
      gatsby-plugin-react-helmet  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-react-helmet
      gatsby-plugin-sharp  >=2.0.31
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp
        gatsby-transformer-sharp  >=2.13.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp
      gatsby-plugin-styled-components  >=3.11.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-styled-components
      gatsby-plugin-typescript  >=2.13.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-typescript
      gatsby-plugin-utils  0.2.27-qod.19 - 0.2.27-qod.21 || 0.2.31-query-modules-debug-missing-sq.23 || >=0.2.35
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-utils
      gatsby-source-filesystem  >=2.12.0-next.0
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-remote-images/node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem
      node_modules/gatsby-source-filesystem
        gatsby-plugin-remote-images  >=3.0.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
        node_modules/gatsby-plugin-remote-images

nth-check  <2.0.1
Severity: moderate
Inefficient Regular Expression Complexity in nth-check - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-rp65-9cf3-cjxr
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install gatsby-plugin-sharp@2.14.4, which is a breaking change
node_modules/svgo/node_modules/nth-check
  css-select  <=3.1.0
  Depends on vulnerable versions of nth-check
  node_modules/svgo/node_modules/css-select
    svgo  1.0.0 - 1.3.2
    Depends on vulnerable versions of css-select
    node_modules/svgo
      gatsby-plugin-sharp  >=2.0.31
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
      Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-utils
      Depends on vulnerable versions of svgo
      node_modules/gatsby-plugin-sharp
        gatsby-plugin-image  >=0.8.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        node_modules/gatsby-plugin-image
          gatsby-source-wordpress  2.0.57-0 - 2.0.57-17 || 2.1.0-alpha.03b9df85 - 3.0.0-rc.9 || 3.11.0-alpha-wordpress.44 - 3.11.0-next.0 || >=3.12.0-next.0
          Depends on vulnerable versions of @rematch/immer
          Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-catch-links
          Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-image
          Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
          Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-source-filesystem
          node_modules/gatsby-source-wordpress
        gatsby-transformer-sharp  >=2.13.0-next.0
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby
        Depends on vulnerable versions of gatsby-plugin-sharp
        node_modules/gatsby-transformer-sharp

object-path  <=0.11.7
Severity: high
Prototype Pollution in object-path - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-8v63-cqqc-6r2c
Prototype Pollution in object-path - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-v39p-96qg-c8rf
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/object-path
  graphql-compose  0.1.0 - 1.5.1 || 7.24.1 - 9.0.2
  Depends on vulnerable versions of object-path
  node_modules/graphql-compose

ws  7.0.0 - 7.4.5
Severity: moderate
ReDoS in Sec-Websocket-Protocol header - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-6fc8-4gx4-v693
fix available via `npm audit fix`
node_modules/ws
  @graphql-tools/url-loader  6.4.1-alpha-0ea0f8b7.0 - 6.10.1
  Depends on vulnerable versions of ws
  node_modules/@graphql-tools/url-loader

36 vulnerabilities (11 moderate, 23 high, 2 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` and your `gatsby-config.js`?

Comment: I edited the posts to include them.

Comment: It seems that some of the files are not properly installed (it doesn't found `gatsby-wordpress-starter-files-main`). Have you tried reinstalling the dependencies (removing `node_modules` and `package-lock.json`) and running a fresh install removing the cache (`gatsby clean`)?

Comment: `gatsby-wordpress-starter-files-main` is the name of the folder. 2 levels down is the src code lives.

Comment: Yes, I already tried deleting package-lock.json and node_modules and did a fresh npm install. But it did not solve the problem. I do have some issues with npm that might be inter-related. Like I have 36 vulnerabilities that I have not been able to get rid of. I have edited the post with this info.